# ffmpeg command to convert interlaced video to progressive without any loss of quality

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Can anyone provide me with the ffmpeg code to convert deinterlaced 80's video to progressive video without any loss of quality - ideally where I could deinterlace only the interlaced fields(I use mediainfo to determine that) and basically preserve all the information in the video.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: 'without any loss of quality' is not really possible. You're going to have to interpolate half of each field, and no matter how you do that you're going to introduce signal loss. If you mean no `perceptible` loss of quality then you're asking a more realistic question.

Answer (score 0):

[FFMpeg video filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) mentioned supporting deinterlacing filters

1. [bwdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-bwdif): Bob Weaver
2. [estdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-estdif): Edge Slope Tracing
3. [kerndeint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-kerndeint): Donald Graft’s adaptive kernel
4. [mcdeint](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-mcdeint): Apply motion-compensation
5. [nnedi](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-nnedi): neural network edge directed interpolation
6. [w3fdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-w3fdif): Weston 3 Field
7. [yadif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-yadif-1): yet another

and [the MSU result](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer.html) includes

1. [bwdif](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#bwdif)
2. [kerndeint](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#kerndeint)
3. [mcdeint](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#mcdeint)
4. [nnedi](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#nnedi)
5. [w3fdif](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#w3fdif)
6. [yadif](https://videoprocessing.ai/benchmarks/deinterlacer-participants.html#yadif)

The best among all FFMpeg filters is the rank 13 **NNEDI**

- MOS: 0.511
- PSNR: 37.099
- SSIM: 0.954
- VMAF: 93.246
- FPS on CPU: *1.910*

However, i would prefer to the rank 14 Bob-Weave Deinterlacer due to the FPS on CPU: *46.450*

At last, people had done [the screen captures of using those filter](https://github.com/kfrn/ffmpeg-things/blob/master/deinterlacing.md), you may take a look for reference

P.S. forget to mention, here is the Bing Chat answer
[image]